# Magento 2: How to get current product name in an observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am using following observer in event.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_cart_save_after">
      <observer name="vendor_module_checkout_cart_save_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartSaveAfterObserver" />
   </event>
  </config>
```

**and here is my observer:**

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    echo "proname: ".$product->getName();die;
}
```

but I am recieving following error:

**Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName() on null**

Can anybody tell me how to get current product  information using above observer?

Answer (score 2):

**1.oneway:**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
            {
               //Product get product name
               $observer->getProduct()->getName();
            }
```

**2.Registry:**

```
$this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
$this->product->getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetQuoteItem ojbect from observer and check as below,

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        echo "product Id: ".$product->getId();die;
    }
```

Comment: getting same error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Comment: Could you replace your event with checkout_cart_product_add_after and check

Comment: I can replace but for some reason I am using that observer and I want that observer anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

First you  this event is only object of `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` as a paramter

> $this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_cart_save_after', ['cart' =>
>   $this]);

**So, you can only call of this class public functions** `getItems()`.

In class this, has a function which give ***you current cart all object.So using this function get all items details***.

```
 public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $cart = $observer->getCart();
        $allitems =  $cart->getItems();
        /* get allitems */
        $lastItem =[];
        if(!empty($allitems)){

                foreach ($allitems as $item) {

                / * add this */
                if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $lastItem[$item->getId()] = $item; 
                }
            // last add item        
            $lastestItem = max($lastItem);
            $lastestItem->getProduct()->getName();  
            $lastestItem->getProduct()->getPrice(); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: is it possible to get only current added item in cart. I donot want to get all items in cart. I only want item that I have added in cart currently.

Comment: Suggest to use event: `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` and which  `$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
            );`

Comment: This event will not give any information of quote item.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know which data you can to use is go to the place where the event is dispatched. So just search by name of event (in your way checkout_cart_save_after). After that you rich this method in Cart Model:

```
 /**
 * Save cart
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function save()
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_cart_save_before', ['cart' => $this]);

    $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
    $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
    $this->quoteRepository->save($this->getQuote());
    $this->_checkoutSession->setQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId());
    /**
     * Cart save usually called after changes with cart items.
     */
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_cart_save_after', ['cart' => $this]);
    $this->reinitializeState();
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see you have data item "cart" that contains this model object. So get it in your observer:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart */
    $cart = $observer->getData('cart');
}
```

After that you will have the cart model and it allows to use any methods of this model. In your way you need products in the cart. For get it use the method **$productIds = $cart->getQuoteProductIds()**. Then if you need to load Product data you should load the product models by Products IDs through ProductRepository. Add to you __construct dependency injection:

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;

/**
 * CheckoutCartSaveAfter constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 */
public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
{
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

For sure don't forgot to use this commands after that:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Then loads product models and get a product name or whatever you want.

```
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product[] $products */
    $products = [];
    foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
        $products[$productId] = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    }

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        var_dump($product->getName());
    }
```

Full example of observer is below:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutCartSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;

/**
 * CheckoutCartSaveAfter constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 */
public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
{
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart */
    $cart = $observer->getData('cart');

    $productIds = $cart->getQuoteProductIds();

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product[] $products */
    $products = [];
    foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
        $products[$productId] = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    }

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        var_dump($product->getName());
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create file inside **app\code\Vendor\MyPackage\Observer\ProductSaveafter.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendo\MyPackage\Observer;
    use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

    class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $productID=$product->getId();            
                var_dump($productID);
                die();
        }
```

Next another file **app\code\Vendor\MyPackage\etc\adminhtml\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="save_example_data" instance="Vendor\MyPackage\Observer\ProductSaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```